# Cómo agrego correctamente un Insert a una base de datos MySQL desde un programa de Java?

Tags: java, mysql, mysqlconnector.jar

estoy haciendo un programa conectado a una base de datos en MySQL y cuando intento hacer un insert en la base de datos desde el programa en envía el error.

este es mi código:

```
try {
        String query = " INSERT INTO Clientes VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);
        preparedStmt.setString (1, "'" + txtCedula.getText() + "'");
        preparedStmt.setString (2, "'" + txtNombre.getText() + "'");
        preparedStmt.setString (3, "'" + txtCelular.getText() + "'");
        preparedStmt.setString (4, "'" + txtPlaca.getText() + "'");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(nuevoCliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Esto es lo que obtengo:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at taller.de.autos.nuevoCliente.jButton1ActionPerformed(nuevoCliente.java:139)
at taller.de.autos.nuevoCliente.access$000(nuevoCliente.java:20)
at taller.de.autos.nuevoCliente$1.actionPerformed(nuevoCliente.java:112)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

Si hago consultas como Select el programa funciona con normalidad :(

Comment: cual es la linea 139 de la clase nuevoCliente?

Comment: es esta PreparedStatement preparedStmt = cn.prepareStatement(query);

Comment: cn probablemente es null

Comment: @JesusCastañeda agrega como inicializas cn

Comment: public class nuevoCliente extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    Connection cn;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs;
    public nuevoCliente() {
        initComponents();
    }   @Jorgesys

Comment: @JesusCastañeda estas declarando cn pero no la estas inicializando?

Comment: Deberías compartir el código completo de todo el ciclo de vida del método, necesito saber como esta creando la conexión a la base de datos, como define el string de conexión donde se define la url del servidor con usuario y contraseña, por otro lado el dejar metodos insert en el código no es lo mas recomendable ya que eso se copila y es difícil cambiar a futuro por lo cual recomiendo utilizar procedimientos almacenados en la base de datos para que puedas modificar el procedimientos así la aplicación se encuentre en producción sin tener una afectación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias a todos los que respondieron y me ayudaron. El problema era que preparaba la instrucción pero nunca la ejecutiva con un método executeQuery()